# Deploy Logic App to Azure via Visual Studio 2019

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-powershell

I am currently trying to weigh up the usage of Logic Apps for part of a project. What I am concerned with is whether deployment has to be done through PowerShell for Visual Studio or if there is another way.
If it does need to be deployed through PowerShell can anyone provide some reliable resources cause Microsoft seems to have multiple guides all doing slightly different things with different versions of powershell.

Overall I'm a little confused and I don't want to adopt a development platform who's deployment options are not well understood by the team.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to deploy your Logic App projects directly from Visual Studio to Azure. Please have a look to [this article](https://microsoft.github.io/AzureTipsAndTricks/blog/blog/tip43.html) explaining how to work with Logic Apps and Visual Studio 2017 (if using VS 2019, please install [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VinaySinghMSFT.AzureLogicAppsToolsForVS2019). Once you have your environment configured, just follow the steps in [this article](https://microsoft.github.io/AzureTipsAndTricks/blog/blog/tip44.html) to deploy your Logic App to Azure. But, honestly, if you are planning to work with a team on these apps, i would recommend you to consider to use Azure DevOps, and deploy your Logic App using a pipeline, so you are following the best practices to manage your code and deploy your apps, and you enable in a better way your team.

## Update

The links above feature blog posts from *Azure Tips and Tricks*, but apparently there are some problems with the images in the posts, so I want to share another relevant article that can help you manage Logic Apps using VS2019/2022.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/manage-logic-apps-with-visual-studio